# When "since" come after a person

Tags: meaning

I wanted to know when "since" come after a person, Is there a change in the meaning of the word? for example, in this context:

> Gödel, the greatest logician **since
>   Aristotle**, was well aware of the logical problems of time travel.
>
> source: Source: The Outer Limits of Reason: What Science, Mathematics, and Logic Cannot Tell Us by Noson S. Yanofsky

Does this mean that "after Aristotle; that is, the Gödel is in the second place after Aristotle" or does it mean "from the time that Aristotle lived until now, Gödel is the biggest logician" or does it mean something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In an expression involving a named person, like 'the greatest logician since Aristotle', the word 'since' has its ordinary and usual dictionary meaning:

> From a particular time in the past until a later time, or until now:

Aristotle was a great logician, and since his death there has been no greater logician than Gödel (in Yanofsky's opinion).

[Since (Cambridge Dictionary)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/since)

Similarly, such expressions as 'the worst dictator since Hitler', 'the funniest comedian since Bob Hope', 'the most intelligent politician since George W Bush', 'the greatest poet since Shelley', are normal, although it is to be noted that they contain a strong element of opinion, about both the first person mentioned, and the second.